Should I still bother to recompile my ruby executable with `jemalloc` on ruby 3.3?
It's been a quite while since I've worked with Ruby, and this used to be a standard step in my dev environment setup.
I don't seem to see any references to recompiling with jemalloc that are from the last 4-5 years; is this still something I should be doing, or is the advice dated?

With ruby 3.3 I would not because it's own memory management is good enough to not need alternative allocators. Unless you have specific (like, data-supported) reasons to use jemalloc, you can rely on the default allocator provided by Ruby and the OS where your app is deployed

In production, yes. Nothing has changed about Ruby's memory management -- it still defaults to glibc on Linux, which scales poorly. jemalloc will save 20-30% of memory.
